# Scaling SVG rect on hover using CSS transform

Tags: css, svg, hover, transform

It seems that applying the same CSS transform on hover to an HTML or SVG element does not create the same effect. As you can see in the following fiddle, the `p` and `rect` do not behave the same way while scaling, and that is precisely my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKD7T/2/

How could I make the `rect` behave exactly as the `p` and scale properly?

I tried scaling the `rect` with a matrix - taking into account the origin point - but it did not seem to work either, or I did it wrong.

I'd like to stick to CSS solutions here but JS ones might also be an option.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems about right.

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>

<svg>
    <g transform="translate(20, 40)">
    <rect x="-20" y="-40" width="50" height="100"/>
    <g transform="translate(55, 0)" >
    <rect x="-20" y="-40" width="50" height="100"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(110, 0)" >
    <rect x="-20" y="-40" width="50" height="100"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(165, 0)" >
    <rect x="-20" y="-40" width="50" height="100"/>
    </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

[It works](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/kZ6sX/) in Firefox [trunk](http://nightly.mozilla.org/) but doesn't seem to work with Firefox 16. I haven't tested Firefox [Beta](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/) or [Aurora](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/aurora/) to see in exactly when it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks, the scaling indeed seems to be the same. However, the `rect` do not take back their initial scale once they have been hovered.

Comment: They do take back their original scale for me with using Firefox trunk on Windows 7.

Comment: That's right, I guess it's no entirely compatible yet then. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add smooth transition effect on svg boxes.

Comment: @dharmendrabisht you should ask that as a separate question.